# How do I get terminator to use syntax highlighting?

Tags: zsh, terminator, syntax-highlighting

When sifting through large amounts of input and output in my terminal emulator (terminator in this case) it would come in handy if I had some syntax highlighting available to make things more readable. Is there any way to do this? While terminator is my preferred terminal emulator I am willing to try others if it is necessary to get the syntax highlighting I would like.

As far as the specifics of the syntax highlighting (like the colours I'd like for the different segments of code) well it does not bother me so long as I can still see it against the black background of terminator. If you wish to switch me to gnome terminal in your answer and want to know it's current background colour for me it's white.

I am currently running zsh as my shell, but am willing to change to bash or any shell environment required to enable syntax highlighting in terminator.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax highlighting is not done by the terminal, is done by the shell; hence you'll need to setup syntax highlighting for the shell.

For Zsh there's [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting):

1. Install `git`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git
   ```
2. Install zsh-syntax-highlighting:

   ```
   git clone git://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting.git
   echo "source ${(q-)PWD}/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh" >> ~/.zshrc
   source ~/.zshrc
   ```

[image]